# Ensuring data integrity when database is accessed by multiple java clients

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, data-integrity

I have one MySql database instance with an *Account* table which maintains a *Balance* field. I have multiple Java applications each using a Jdbc to connect to the database that can potentially increase or decrease the value of the *Balance* field. How do I ensure that the *Balance* value is read, calculated and updated and that this process happens in isolation, and is 'aware' of any other Java processes that might be in the middle of doing the same thing?

Comment: This is why RDBMSs have been invented in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is to use transactions:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

However, in the case you describe, I much prefer not to store the balance of an account as a column in a table, but to calculate it by summing the value of the transactions related to that account. It's far less sensitive to the integrity issues you raise, and you're less likely to run into obscure locking scenarios.

Comment: In a long lived account which has had 1000's of transactions would you always sum those to find the balance each time? Or is there some sort of strategy to avoid this, like maintaining a per year balance?

Comment: In general, a well-tuned database system doesn't really slow down noticably between hundreds and (tens of) thousands of records in a SUM. Of course, if you have to work out the balance of thousands of accounts, that might not be so easy. In that case, I've used a strategy similar to what you suggest: effectively, archiving historic transactions, and creating an "opening balance" transaction with the sum of those archived transactions.

Answer (score 2):

One simple approach is JDBCs transaction management. See [`java.sql.Connection.setAutoCommit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) documentation. It enables you to explicitly disable automatic statement commits:

```
Connection c = /* retrieve connection */
c.setAutoCommit(false);
c.setTransactionIsolation(/* depends on your requirements */);
c.executeQuery(/*  */);
c.executeUpdate(/*  */);
c.commit(); /* or c.rollback() */
```

In a real world scenario you must introduce a `finally` block to commit or rolback the transaction, otherwise you may end up with deadlocks in your database.

Edit: If your Java applications are end user clients, you are always in risk that users directly connect to the database (e.g. using Access) bypassing your transaction management logic. That's one reason we began to place application servers in between. A solution might also be to implement a stored procedure, so that the clients do not interact with the tables at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using InnoDB engine, then you can use [MySQL record level locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-locking.html) to lock specific account record for updates from other clients.

**UPDATE:** Alternitively you can application-level locks described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock).

Comment: From the reference manual - 'Deadlocks are possible...' and 'Generally, table locks are superior to row-level locks' - doesn't inspire confidence. Have you used row level locking and is it simple to use effectively? Do you have any sample code of how you would preform the 'lock' using Jdbc?  Thanks.